# Not able to edit fields in experience editor after upgrading to Sitecore 9.2 with glass 5.6

Tags: experience-editor, glass-mapper, upgrade

Working on an upgrade from Sitecore 8.2 to 9.2, I also upgraded glassmapper 4.3 to  5.6

In glass 5 also some changes in the controllers:

Glass 4:

```
public class MainVisualController : GlassController
{
    public ActionResult MainVisual()
    {
        var datasource = this.GetDataSourceItem<MainVisual>(false, true);
        var parameters = this.GetRenderingParameters<MainVisualRenderingParams>();

        var model = Mapper.Map<MainVisualJsonDto>(datasource).Map(parameters);

        return this.React(Constants.FrontendComponents.Sections.MainVisual, model);
    }
}
```

Glass 5:

```
public class MainVisualController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMvcContext mvcContext;

    public MainVisualController(IMvcContext mvcContext)
    {
        this.mvcContext = mvcContext;
    }

    public ActionResult MainVisual()
    {
        var datasource = this.mvcContext.GetDataSourceItem<MainVisual>();
        var parameters = this.mvcContext.GetRenderingParameters<MainVisualRenderingParams>();

        var model = Mapper.Map<MainVisualJsonDto>(datasource).Map(parameters);

        return this.React(Constants.FrontendComponents.Sections.MainVisual, model);
    }
}
```

Note that I use `Controller` (`System.Web.Mvc.Controller`) instead of `GlassController`, and added a constructor to inject `IMvcContext`.

The MainVisual model contains an `Image` field and a `Title` field.
Everything works fine on Content Delivery, but in the CMS in Experience Editor, I noticed that the `Title` field and all other field on all components are not editable anymore.

Looking at this specific field `datasource.Title`, I see that on Sitecore 8.2 and Glass 4.3 it contains the edit control:

`<input id='fld_47711AD1CF72485C8CE9396ADE6632D7_0C618E0645B548388776EB49D331C20D_nl-NL_1_e990f673e4e5419b9c9c124de93354b3_382' class='scFieldValue' name='fld_47711AD1CF72485C8CE9396ADE6632D7_0C618E0645B548388776EB49D331C20D_nl-NL_1_e990f673e4e5419b9c9c124de93354b3_382' type='hidden' value="Welcome to the website" /><span class="scChromeData">{"commands":[{"click":"chrome:common:edititem({command:\"webedit:open\"})","header":"Edit the related item","icon":"/temp/iconcache/office/16x16/cubes.png","disabledIcon":"/temp/cubes_disabled16x16.png","isDivider":false,"tooltip":"Edit the related item in the Content Editor.","type":"common"},{"click":"chrome:rendering:personalize({command:\"webedit:personalize\"})","header":"Personalize","icon":"/temp/iconcache/office/16x16/users_family.png","disabledIcon":"/temp/users_family_disabled16x16.png","isDivider":false,"tooltip":"Create or edit personalization for this component.","type":"sticky"}],"contextItemUri":"sitecore://master/{47711AD1-CF72-485C-8CE9-396ADE6632D7}?lang=nl-NL&ver=1","custom":{},"displayName":"Title","expandedDisplayName":null}</span><span id="fld_47711AD1CF72485C8CE9396ADE6632D7_0C618E0645B548388776EB49D331C20D_nl-NL_1_e990f673e4e5419b9c9c124de93354b3_382_edit" sc_parameters="prevent-line-break=true" contenteditable="true" class="scWebEditInput" scFieldType="single-line text" scDefaultText="[No text in field]">Welcome to the website</span>`

But in Sitecore 9.2 with glass 5.6 using the experience editor, I only see the field value in `datasource.Title`:
*Welcome to the website*

This results in components where nothing can be edited. 
What could be causing this? Reviewing the [upgrade to V5 documentation](http://glass.lu/mapper/documentation/Upgrade-ToV5) does not give me any clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of the problem.

It was caused by myself during the upgrade of glassmapper. The views are rendered by React and therefore it is needed that the models already contain the rendered fields in experience editor mode.

By installing a higher version of the glassmapper nuget package the files `App_Start\GlassMapperSc.cs` and `App_Start\GlassMapperScCustom.cs` were reverted to the default. And in my GlassMapperScCustom a custom DataMapperFactory was added to the dependencyResolver. In that datamapper the GetFieldValue was overriden containing this piece of code:

```
    public override object GetFieldValue(
        string fieldValue,
        SitecoreFieldConfiguration config,
        SitecoreDataMappingContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            return FieldRenderer.Render(
                context.Item,
                config.FieldId.ToString(),
                "Cacheable=true&Cache_VaryByData=true");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.logger.Error("Error getting field value.", ex);
        }

        return fieldValue;
    }
```

That was the reason that the models are already containing all the json needed for the frontend React code to render an editable field. It took me a while to figure out that the customization that was applied on glassmapper was undone during the upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Please change requestValidationMode="4.0" to requestValidationMode="4.5" in web.config file. It was working for me.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for me.